# Using ranges in adding constraints to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance for your support. I am using VBA and have some range named in the name manager in excel that I want to use in my solver, using a For cycle to let the system automatically add constraints and condition.

I wrote down this script but it doesn't work:

```
Dim Prezzi(1 To 10) As Variant
Dim Spread_Fwd(1 To 10) As Variant
Dim Medie(1 To 10) As Variant
Dim Differenze(1 To 10) As Variant


Prezzi_1 = Range("Prezzi")
Spread_Fwd_1 = Range("Spread_Fwd")
Medie_1 = Range("Medie")
Differenze_1 = Range("Differenze")

For i = 1 To 1

    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="Differenze_1(" & i & ",1)", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="Spread_Fwd_1(" & i & ",1)"
           SolverOk SetCell:="Medie_1("     & i & ",1)", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="5,8", ByChange:="CALIBRATION" _
        , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

but it doesn't work. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very useful description of your problem.  What happens when you run your code?  Do you get an error?  If Yes, what is it?

Comment: Sorry for that mate! The error is "Error in model. Please verify that all the cell and Contstaints are valid."

Comment: Your array are arrays of cell *values*, not arrays of *cell ranges*, so you cannot assign an element of those arrays to a parameter which expects a Range-type argument. I'm not super-familiar with Solver, so it would help to show the code (you recorded using Macro recorder?) before you made your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think your cell ref's should look more like: `Cellref:=Differenze_1(i ,1).value`.

As Differenze_1 is an object, it shouldn't be in string form, but returning the value from the cell.